# finding nearest edge to a gps point by querying OpenStreetMap in Athena

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-athena, osmnx

Previously I have used OSMnx library in python to get the closest drive way to a particular gps datapoint. To do so I was using following code:

```
places=['Nebraska, USA']
G=ox.graph_from_place(places,network_type='drive')
origin_point = (lat, long) 
nearest_edge = ox.get_nearest_edge(G, origin_point)
```

Now what I want to do is querying OpenStreetMap with Athena for the same thing (still in the python). I want to give bunch of gps datapoints and for each datapoint get the closest road. Does anyone know how I should do this?
Also if you know any documentation which can help I really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Athena and Presto support [Geo-spatial functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/geospatial.html) such as:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Point(-71.0882, 42.3607), ST_Point(-74.1197, 40.6976))
```

Based on the dataset that you want to focus on and its format you can build in S3 a databased on the location that you care about such as roads in Nebraska, USA, and query against it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing the documentation. However I searched in it and I couldn't find any function to find the closest edge to a particular point. The only function that I found a potential for this issue was line_locate_point(linestring,point) where I can find the closest point on a LineString to the given point. Then I can get another query to see that particular point is located on which edge (I don't know how but there should be a way for it). Do you have any other method in mind which could be more efficient?